# How to track the execution process of ruby program

Tags: ruby, trace, execution

I am new to ruby and I want to track the execution process of ruby program when I feel confused about some programs. I wonder whether there is a way to help me track just as shell scripts `set -x` do?

PS:

Such as shell script test.sh:

```
set -x
ls /home
echo "hello dujun and haotianma!"
```

when I execute test.sh, then the output will be like:

```
+ ls /home
dujun  haotianma
+ echo 'hello dujun and haotianma!'
hello dujun and haotianma!
```

Just as how this bash script echos each statement before executing it, I want to make a Ruby program show which statements are executing.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think you can use the Ruby's stdlib [`Tracer`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/tracer/rdoc/Tracer.html).

I wrote a code in my `test.rb` file :

```
require 'tracer'

Tracer.on

class A
  def square(a)
    @b = a*a
    result
  end
  def result
    @b
  end
end

a = A.new
puts a.square(5)

Tracer.off
```

Now run the code, and see all what's going on under the hood :

```
(arup~>Ruby)$ ruby test.rb
#0:test.rb:5::-: class A
#0:test.rb:5::C: class A
#0:test.rb:6::-:   def square(a)
#0:test.rb:10::-:   def result
#0:test.rb:13::E: end
#0:test.rb:15::-: a = A.new
#0:test.rb:16::-: puts a.square(5)
#0:test.rb:6:A:>:   def square(a)
#0:test.rb:7:A:-:     @b = a*a
#0:test.rb:8:A:-:     result
#0:test.rb:10:A:>:   def result
#0:test.rb:11:A:-:     @b
#0:test.rb:12:A:<:   end
#0:test.rb:9:A:<:   end
25
#0:test.rb:18::-: Tracer.off
(arup~>Ruby)$
```

---

Again look at the code. Now I changed trace point.

```
require 'tracer'

class A
  def square(a)
    @b = a*a
    result
  end
  def result
    @b
  end
end

Tracer.on

a = A.new
puts a.square(5)

Tracer.off
```

Now run the code, and see all what's going on under the hood :

```
(arup~>Ruby)$ ruby test.rb
#0:test.rb:15::-: a = A.new
#0:test.rb:16::-: puts a.square(5)
#0:test.rb:4:A:>:   def square(a)
#0:test.rb:5:A:-:     @b = a*a
#0:test.rb:6:A:-:     result
#0:test.rb:8:A:>:   def result
#0:test.rb:9:A:-:     @b
#0:test.rb:10:A:<:   end
#0:test.rb:7:A:<:   end
25
#0:test.rb:18::-: Tracer.off
(arup~>Ruby)$
```

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Thanks, that you told me "nice"... I never had any appreciation from you.. I am glad today. :-)

Comment: I'm not a mean person, you know :)

Comment: Cool! Didn't about the `Tracer` class! +1

Comment: @Abdo Yes, I think there is nothing present still in Ruby for tracing the variable.