# What are the values of these Ruby instance variables throughout execution?

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to trace the value of the instance variables `@x`, `@y`, and `@z` while the program executes:

```
class S    
  def initialize(theX, theY)
    @x = theX + 2
    @y = theY + 3
  end

  def f(n)
    @x = n * @x + @y
    @y = @x + (n + 1) * @y
  end

  def to_s
    return (@y + 1).to_s + " " + (@x + 2).to_s  
  end
end

class T < S
  def initialize
    super(1, 4)
    @z = @x + @y + 3
  end

  def f(m)
    super(3)
    @z *= m   
  end

  def to_s
    return super + " " + (@z + 3).to_s
  end
end

s = S.new(6, 5)
s.f(3)
print s, "\n"
t = T.new
t.f(7)
print t, "\n"
```

The final output is:

```
65 34
45 18 94
```

Can anyone provide a step-by-step illustration of how the program's execution results in these values?

Comment: can you show me how variable trace is done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to follow the image I have below or check out @ArupRakshit's answer at [How to track the execution process of ruby program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21810588/how-to-track-the-execution-process-of-ruby-program/21810792#21810792)

[image]

Comment: Did you create it manually ? :-)

Comment: @ArupRakshit yup... I did it in a Google doc =) It was very late at night to create something that aliases all the methods and print out the trace :-)

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21810588/how-to-track-the-execution-process-of-ruby-program/21810792#21810792) ?