# print ruby code during execution

Tags: ruby, bash, continuous-integration

Does Ruby have the ability to print out each line of code as it executes during runtime? I'm looking for something similar to Bash's `set -x` functionality.

Preferably the solution would be something using only the Ruby standard-lib. This would be used in a continuous-integration system so I don't have much control over installed gems.

Thank you in advance

Comment: wow this is a dupe. knowing what words to use when searching is tough sometimes.

Comment: I answered there.. still it took more than 5 mins to search it ... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by Arup, this is a [dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21810588/how-to-track-the-execution-process-of-ruby-program).

Ruby's `Tracer` class fits my needs.